# Does Chrome Web Drivers needs to be in Client's System while using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have tried searching the official documentation, but no result. Does Chrome Web Driver needs to be in client's system for a python script using Selenium to run? I basically want to distribute compiled or executable file versions of the application to the end user. How do i include Chrome Web driver with that package?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to download and put chromedriver to your system and then need to call in selenium code.

Download chromedriver from here : [Chromedriver for selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Below code will help you to call chrome driver using selenium with python :

```
  import os
  from selenium import webdriver

  chromedriver = "/Users/mike/Downloads/chromedriver" [you please put your actual path of chrome driver]
  os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

Hope this help you.

If you are using selenium RC , then you can set path like below :

```
  selenium = new DefaultSelenium(Server, ServerPort, "*googlechrome", DomainURL);
```

Comment: I guess you haven't read the question right. I have chromedriver installed. I want to distribute my application to other users. Does the end user need to have it installed? If so, where should be the location?

Comment: Do you using Selenium Grid? and if you are going to distribute your application that that will be on server , right? how you are distributing? by URL?

Comment: No i am not using remote server. It's just a desktop application. In order for the user to be able to run the application, how does he install Chrome driver. For developers, we enter the System path variable and place the .exe file there. But wouldn't it be a complicated process for users?

Comment: Then you just install chrome driver in server and set server path so no need to install in each desktop.

Comment: Then you can set path like :                                       selenium = new DefaultSelenium(Server, ServerPort,
                                          "*googlechrome", DomainURL);

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way i can set the path relative to the program directory, so i can just place it in the folder where the pyc file exists and distribute the whole package to the users.

Comment: About that I have not idea...I am updating answer so please accept if it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

`chromedriver` needs to be installed on the machine that will launch the instance of the Chrome browser.

If the machine that launches the Chrome instance is the same machine as where the Python script resides, then the answer to your question is "yes".

If the machine that launches the Chrome instance is a machine different from the machine that runs your Python script, then the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: Thanks.. but where should the location of it be on that machine? The paths would be obviously different if we hardcode it.

Comment: `chromedriver` can be installed anywhere you want, so long as you tell Selenium where to find it. This is [documented here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#Troubleshooting).